# Ninject: Get the instance injected to a parent object

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a crazy dependency injection case which I'll explain, but first let me show you some code:

```
  class Foo : IFoo
  {
    Foo(
      IBar bar,
      IFooContext context,
      IService service)
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  class Service : IService
  {
    Service(
      IBar bar)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

I'm resolving dependencies using Ninject. All of the above are `InTransientScope`. `IBar` is provided by a factory method, which uses one of the `IFooContext` properties for creation. What I want to achieve is to have `Service` injected into `Foo` with the same `IBar` instance that was injected into `Foo`.

I have no idea how to achieve this with Ninject. Is it even possible? If not, I'm thinking about exposing `IBar` property in `IService` and setting it in `Foo` constructor, but honestly I don't like this idea.

I simplified my case for sake of...simplicity, but in reality `Foo` is Rebus message handler, `IFooContext` is a message context, `IBar` is a logger. I want to format logger messages so that they include ID from a Rebus message being handled. And I want both `Foo`'s and `Service`'s log events to have that ID.

Comment: Then that sounds more like IBar should have a request scoped lifetime and not transient. https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) who pointed me towards right direction, I've managed to get what I wanted:

```
Bind<IFoo>()
  .To<Foo>
  .InScope(ctx => FooContext.Current);

Bind<IBar>()
  .ToMethod(ctx =>
  {
    var scope = ctx.GetScope() as IFooContext;
    // Some logic to create Bar by IFooContext...
  });

Bind<IService>()
  .To<Service>
  .InScope(ctx => FooContext.Current);
```

As I said, in reality `Foo` is a Rebus message handler. For my example that means, that for every `Foo` new `IFooContext` is created and also I have access to current one.

As for [Jan Muncinsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5296462/jan-muncinsky)'s answer - I didn't test it, but from what I read from Ninject's documentation, it seems that it's also a valid solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/wiki/InNamedScope)

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().DefinesNamedScope("FooScope");
kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>().InNamedScope("FooScope");
```